# What does it exactly mean to be a Hegelian in terms of politics what are they opposed to?

Tags: hegel, dialectic, foucault

Does it simply mean viewing the progression of history as dialectic where internal contradictions within the imagining of a thesis sort themselves out dialectically ?

Does it mean a belief in historicism ? Slavoj Zizek calls himself a Hegelian but opposes Historicism.

Also, Zizek recounts that Hegel provides a much better understanding of history than Foucault. Is hegelianism simply a revolt against he dominance of foucault in academia ?